# Appending two lists together

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun tree-node(x)
(list(* 2 x) (+(* 2 x) 1))
(tree-node 4)
(8 9)

 (defun special-queue(y)
 (set x (list y (+ 1 y) (+ 2 y)))
 (append(list(rest z) (tree-node first z)))
 )
```

Above is the code i have so far. I am trying to append two lists together into one list. the first function takes in a number and returns a list of two numbers. the second function is intended to take in a list, apply the tree-node function to the first element in that list and then append both the original list and the tree node list together. For example: (3,4,5)<-(list function takes in), (4,5,6,7)<- appended list that 6, 7 are the tree-node function list. The first element is removed once the tree-node function is applied to it.

Comment: `(set x ...)` doesn't do what you probably think it does. `set` is a function in Common Lisp, that largely exists for backward compatibility with ancient Lisp. `(set x 42)` evaluates `x` as a variable, and the passes the value of `x` to `set`. The value must be a symbol. The function will store `42` into the dynamic/global function binding of that symbol. That symbol likely isn't `x`, unless `x` has itself as a value.  TL:DR: you probably want `setf` or `setq`.

Comment: you need to format your code properly; it is unreadable now.

Comment: Also with global variables like `x` and `z` they should have `*earnuffs*` so that they stand out as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list `a` and a list `b`, you get the two appended by applying `append` to them:

```
(append a b)
```

Note that what you wrote is effectively:

```
(append (list a b))  ; wrong
```

To establish a local binding, use `let`:

```
(let ((initial-queue (list n (+ n 1) (+ n 2))))
  (append (rest initial-queue) (child-indices (first initial-queue))))
```